# JQuery's toggle function is affecting too many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, toggle

This is what should happen: When I click an image `'.post-text'` should appear, then - when I click the image once more - the image disappears. All this happens in the toggle function but I have simplified it here.

This is what actually happens: When I click one image, the `'.post-text'` of all the blocks are opened immediately. I need that to only open the one that I click. I have tried what you see below and the find function, but it doesn't work. Please help me.

```
 $( ".down-text img" ).click(function() {
        $(".post-text" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: What i understand from this is you need to use 'id' rather than 'classes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes

but with that you will be needing some traversing

supposing your **.post-text** is the next div after your image

```
 $( ".down-text img" ).click(function() {
      $(this).next(".post-text" ).toggle( "slow" );
  });
```

> see jquery **next()** | **find()** | **parent()**
>
> https://api.jquery.com/next/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/parent/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this)` to target the element you just clicked:

```
$( ".down-text img" ).click(function() {
  $(this).find(".post-text" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes can help here.

If you add a data attribute called *text* to your HTML image element:

```
<img data-text="text1"/>
```

And a matching one to your text element:

```
<div class="post-text" data-text="text1">Here is some text</div>
```

You can then use that information to only open the correct text element rather than all of the elements that share the same class:

```
$('.down-text img').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('text');
    $('.post-text[data-text="' + id + '"]').toggle("slow");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v1kbubau/7/)